# Adding FloatCanvas to Panel - Wx Python

Tags: python, wxpython

I have this panel class that aims to add a `FloatCanvas.ScaledBitmap2` to a Frame.

```
class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
            self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.WHITE)
    
            # Add canvas
            canvas = NavCanvas.NavCanvas(self, BackgroundColor="WHITE").Canvas
            canvas.MaxScale = 20  # sets the maximum zoom level
            self.canvas = canvas
            self.canvas.Draw()
    
            # events
            self.canvas.Bind(FloatCanvas.EVT_MOTION, self.OnMove)
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.on_resize)
    
        def update_slide_image(self, slide):
            slide_image = slide.get_image(self)
    
            w, h = self.GetSize()
    
            img = FloatCanvas.ScaledBitmap2(slide_image, (550, 660), Height=h, Position='cc', InForeground=True)
    
            self.canvas.AddObject(img)
            self.canvas.Draw()
            self.canvas.ZoomToBB()
```

Then I add it to the my frame like this:

```
def init_panels(self):

    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    sizer.Add(self.main_panel, proportion=5, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, border=5)
    sizer.Add(self.sub_panel, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, border=5)

    self.SetSizer(sizer)
    sizer.Fit(self)
    self.Layout()
```

But I get this:
[image]
As you can see, the image is not showing, only the submenu. Of course I call update_slide_image() during the program execution.

Comment: I don't see where the `FloatCanvas` is added, in the code provided, except in `update_slide_image` which doesn't appear to be called and if it were to be called, would need the parameter `slide`.

Comment: it is called, I said that.

Comment: Incomplete code snippets invite people to simply guess. We can not check what we can not see. Try a `self.Refresh()` or `self.Update()` after calling the update. Incidentally, `proportion=5`, is the main_panel really meant to be 5 times bigger than `sub_panel`?

Comment: You might also try `self.canvas.Draw(Force=True)`.  A minimal, workable example would be useful in situations such as this, rather than partial code snippets.